# Simple way to add leading space to single digit datepart(day,...)

Tags: t-sql

Using SQL Server 2014, I am working on a way to provide a list of date ranges. While I am getting the correct date ranges, I am left with a cosmetic task: add a leading space to single digit day values.

[image: Date range without leading space]

This is the code that produces the value shown in the screenshot.

```
DECLARE @int INT = 6;
/* to add 6 days to start of date range*/

SELECT DateRange = CONCAT (
        left(DATENAME(MONTH, d.DATE), 3),
        ' ',
        datepart(day, d.DATE),
        ' — ',
        datepart(day, DATEADD(day, @int, d.DATE))
        )
FROM dbo.CalendarFundingDays d
WHERE d.SchoolYear = '16-17'
    AND datepart(WEEKDAY, d.DATE) = 2
```

In order to produce the leading space for single-digit day values, I *could* throw in some case logic, but it looks very ugly.

```
DECLARE @int INT = 6;
/* to add 6 days to start of date range*/

SELECT DateRange = CONCAT (
        left(DATENAME(MONTH, d.DATE), 3),
        ' ',
        CASE 
            WHEN len(cast(datepart(day, d.DATE) AS NVARCHAR(2))) = 1
                THEN CONCAT (
                        ' ',
                        cast(datepart(day, d.DATE) AS NVARCHAR(2))
                        )
            ELSE cast(datepart(day, d.DATE) AS NVARCHAR(2))
            END,
        ' — ',
        left(DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(day, @int, d.DATE)), 3),
        ' ',
        CASE 
            WHEN len(cast(datepart(day, DATEADD(day, @int, d.DATE)) AS NVARCHAR(2))) = 1
                THEN CONCAT (
                        ' ',
                        cast(datepart(day, DATEADD(day, @int, d.DATE)) AS NVARCHAR(2))
                        )
            ELSE cast(datepart(day, DATEADD(day, @int, d.DATE)) AS NVARCHAR(2))
            END
        )
FROM dbo.CalendarFundingDays d
WHERE datepart(WEEKDAY, d.DATE) = 2;
```

While the result is what I need, the code is ugly and hard to read. Is there a simpler way to produce the same result?

[image: This is the desired format]

Comment: Your format is quite strange when a range spans months.like "Sep 26 - 2" what version are you on?

Comment: I see what's happening. That should have been 'Sep 26 - Oct  2'.

Comment: Could you return the start day, start month, end day and end month of the range as seperate columns and then do the formating in the UI layer of your application?

Comment: This one table has multiple uses and multiple destinations. I was really hoping I could address the formatting issue in this table, as other users might not think of doing the formatting on their end.

Comment: You still haven't answered what version of SQL Server

Comment: So the FORMAT function will be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DateRange = CONCAT (
        left(DATENAME(MONTH, d.DATE), 3),
        ' ',
        RIGHT(' ' + CAST(datepart(day, d.DATE) AS NVARCHAR(2)),2),
        ' — ',
        RIGHT(' ' + CAST(datepart(day, DATEADD(day, @int, d.DATE)) AS NVARCHAR(2)),2)
    )
FROM dbo.CalendarFundingDays d
WHERE d.SchoolYear = '16-17'
AND datepart(WEEKDAY, d.DATE) = 2
```

Comment: This produces the intended result and is amazingly simple.

Comment: I put in the CAST just in case, but I think it's probably not necessary. Cleans it up a bit if you feel comfortable removing it.

Comment: I tried it without the cast, and the leading spaces were not there. The Cast is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It's SQL Server 2014 so you really might as well take advantage of the `format()` function. This allows you to easily make tweaks and eliminates a lot of the messing snipping of date parts. The `case` handles ranges when the start and end months aren't the same (assuming you don't want to repeat the month portion:)

```
replace(
    concat(
        format(@d1, 'MMM dd'),
        ' - ',
        format(@d2,
            case when datediff(month, @d1, @d2) <> 0
                 then 'MMM dd' else 'dd' end
        )
    ), ' 0', '  ');
```

Generically the `<space>0` pattern won't always be reliable but you could use a special marker in the format to save the place for substitution afterward:

```
replace(replace(
    concat(
        format(@d1, 'MMM ^dd'),
        ' - ',
        format(@d2,
            case when datediff(month, @d1, @d2) <> 0
                 then 'MMM ' else '' end + '^dd'
        )
    ), '^0', ' '), '^', '');
```